# Ubuntu and installing Eclipse to support C++ and Java

Tags: java, c++, eclipse, ubuntu

This is probably one of the most confusing things I've had since I haven't used Unix too much before.
I have Ubuntu and I need to install my IDE (Eclipse) to support Java and C++.
I got Eclipse through the software center, then through the terminal's `apt-get` I installed openjdk for java, it appeared as a "Java project" in eclipse but it wouldn't compile, for example if I write `System.out.println("something");` it does not even compile the `System.out.println` as it does not recognize it.

So can someone please once and for all refer me to a tutorial on how to install all these (and configure it) correctly? I have only found tips here and on google, nothing that -really- explains, and most the tutorials on how to install eclipse with java wants you to get `sun-java-6-jdk` which is not available anymore in the `apt-cache`

Comment: Just replace the 6 with 7. In addition, look up your eclipse.ini file and enter the correct JVM Path there.

Comment: @Ingo - you should make this an answer, I think

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you have not installed the java properly :

Step 1 : Download java binaries from oracle.com/

Step 2 : Extract the compressed folder in your home directory `/home`

you can either right click on the tar ball and choose "Extract" option or you can use

```
[user@user-pc ~]$ tar xzvf <filename>.tar.gz
```

example : [user@user-pc ~]$ tar xzvf jdk-7u3-linux-x64.tar.gz

Step 3 :

Once its extracted, switch to root user

```
[user@user-pc ~]$  su
```

and execute the following commands:

```
[root@user-pc ~]# update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/java java /home/<extracted_folder_name>/bin/java 1

[root@user-pc ~]# update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/javac javac /home/<extracted_folder_name>/bin/javac 1

[root@user-pc ~]# update-alternatives --set java /home/<extracted_folder_name>/bin/java

[root@user-pc ~]# update-alternatives --set javac /home/<extracted_folder_name>/bin/javac
```

I have tried this on Linux Mint, though I make and educated guess that it should work fine for almost all Linux Debian Distros.

Restart your eclipse and it should work fine.